# Using MAX() and COUNT() in the same query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out what language a user answers in the most, and return by `user_id`, the `language_id` they answer in the most and how many times they have answers.

I began by `SELECT`ing a table/sub-table which returns these results:

```
Table: `sub-selected`
`user_id`    `language_id`    `answers`
  1               1               1
  2               1               1
  1               2               5
  2               2               2
  1               4               3
  1               5               1
```

This table returns the `user_id`, the `language_id`, and how many times that `language_id` has been answered by the user. I used this query to get it:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t2.to_language_id, COUNT(t2.to_language_id) as answers
FROM translation_results as t1
LEFT JOIN translations as t2
ON t2.translation_id = t1.translation_id
GROUP BY t2.to_language_id, t1.user_id
```

The table structure is:

```
Table: `translations`
`translation_id`    `from_phrase_id`    `to_language_id`

Table: `translation_results`
`translation_id`    `result_id` PRI-AI    `user_id`
```

The `translations` table stores all the translations requested, and the translation_results table stores the answers to those translations and the respective `user_id`.

So, to sum up the table and to get the user_id, their most answered `language_id`, and how many times they answered in that `language_id`, I used:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.to_language_id, MAX(t1.answers)
FROM (
    //The sub-table
    SELECT t1.user_id, t2.to_language_id, COUNT(t2.to_language_id) as answers
    FROM translation_results as t1
    LEFT JOIN translations as t2
    ON t2.translation_id = t1.translation_id
    GROUP BY t2.to_language_id, t1.user_id
) as t1
GROUP BY t1.user_id, t1.to_language_id
```

But this does not collapse the table into the desired structure and instead returns:

```
Table: `sub-selected`
`user_id`    `language_id`    `answers`
  1               1               1
  1               2               5
  1               4               3
  1               5               1
  2               1               1
  2               2               2
```

I know it is affected by the group by of `two clauses`, but then if I only group by user_id and do not include to_language_id in my selected columns, I can't know which respective language_id is the most answered. I have also tried sub-queries and a few joins, but I find I constantly need to use `MAX(t1.answers)` regardless in the selected columns and thus destroys my hopes of collasping the `group by` correctly.  How can I collapse the query correctly instead of having `group by` find all the unique `MAX()` combinations of `user_id` and `to_language_id`?

Comment: Hi can you create [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some data and add to your question desired output? tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get:

> the `user_id`, their most answered `language_id`, and how many times they
>   answered in that language_id

you can use variables:

```
SELECT user_id, language_id, answers
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, language_id, answers,
         @rn:= IF(@uid = user_id,
                  IF(@uid:=user_id, @rn:=@rn+1, @rn:=@rn+1),
                  IF(@uid:=user_id, @rn:=1, @rn:=1)) AS rn
  FROM (SELECT t1.user_id, t2.to_language_id AS language_id, 
               COUNT(t2.to_language_id) as answers     
        FROM translation_results as t1 
        LEFT JOIN translations as t2 
           ON t2.translation_id = t1.translation_id
        GROUP BY t2.to_language_id, t1.user_id 
       ) t
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0, @uid:=0) AS vars
  ORDER BY user_id, answers DESC
) s
WHERE s.rn = 1
```

There is a limitation however in the above query: if there are more than one `language_id` sharing the same maximum number of answers for a `user_id`, then only one will be returned.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/707ce/10)

An alternative way, is to use you query twice as a derived table:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, language_id, t1.answers
FROM (SELECT t1.user_id, t2.to_language_id AS language_id, 
             COUNT(t2.to_language_id) as answers
      FROM translation_results as t1
      LEFT JOIN translations as t2
         ON t2.translation_id = t1.translation_id
      GROUP BY t2.to_language_id, t1.user_id ) t1
INNER JOIN (      
   SELECT user_id, MAX(answers) AS answers
   FROM (SELECT t1.user_id, t2.to_language_id, 
                COUNT(t2.to_language_id) as answers
         FROM translation_results as t1
         LEFT JOIN translations as t2
            ON t2.translation_id = t1.translation_id
         GROUP BY t2.to_language_id, t1.user_id 
        ) t
   GROUP BY user_id ) t2
ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.answers = t2.answers
```

This query does not have the limitation of the previous query, but is likely to be less efficient compared to the previous one.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/707ce/15)

Answer (score 0):

If I undestood your question, you should define a temporary or derived table with the result of the subquery, lets call is `sub_selected`, then you should do:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.to_language_id, answers
FROM sub_selected as t1
WHERE t1.answers = 
   (SELECT MAX(answers)
     FROM sub_selected t2
     WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id and t1.to_language_id = t2.language_id)
```